# Extracting data from API to html elements

Tags: html, regex, api

I am not an experienced coder so excuse me if my explanation isn't perfect.

I'm making an html page and I'd like there to be a section that shows some Osu! stats. There's this osu api that spits out all of the information I could possibly need but there's a litle bit too much of it.

https://osu.ppy.sh/api/get_user?k=ff96ad02d159e0acad3282ad33e43a710dac96d5&u=Sceleri

The above returns:

```
[{"user_id":"6962718","username":"Sceleri","count300":"93129","count100":"15744","count50":"3404","playcount":"776","ranked_score":"184300015","total_score":"258886799","pp_rank":"345687","level":"34.115","pp_raw":"314.239","accuracy":"94.54791259765625","count_rank_ss":"1","count_rank_s":"55","count_rank_a":"74","country":"FI","pp_country_rank":"4112","events":[]}]
```

I'd like to parse a few numbers from there. Example:

```
"pp_raw":"314.239" -> <p>;314.239</p>;
```

The `<p>` would be inside a div and so on, where I can specify some `CSS` to it and make it look good. The main problem is extracting the data to separate `<p>` elements.

I have executed this with regex in Rainmeter before (I had help) but I have no idea how to do it in html.

Answer (score 1):

Use Jquery ajax calls. The url you posted basically gives you a json object.

HTML:

```
<div id="pp_raw">
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$.get( "https://osu.ppy.sh/api/get_user?k=ff96ad02d159e0acad3282ad33e43a710dac96d5&u=Sceleri", function( data ) {
  //You can put whatever you want in the style attr to make things pretty
  $( "#pp_raw" ).html("<p style='color:red'>"+data[0]['pp_raw']+"</p> ");
});
```

JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/rwt5mdyk/8/

Comment: This answer would be even better if it addressed the portion of the question that speaks of CSS styles. Regardless, my ++.

Comment: One point of order: it is not a good idea to insert data into HTML using string concatenation. I would recommend using the jQuery `text` method to insert it. So first `$("#pp_raw").html("<p style='color:red;'></p>");` then `$('#pp_raw p').text(data[0]["pp_raw"]);`. Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rwt5mdyk/9/